# Absolute fastest (and hopefully elegant) way to return a certain char buffer given a struct type

Tags: c++, templates, struct, mapping, low-latency

OK first and foremost, performance is most important here so I doubt a map would work.  I have a list of structs (about 16 of them) like

```
struct A { ... };
struct B { ... }; 
...
```

each are different and each are of different sizes.

I'm wondering what elegant way we might be able to do something along the lines of:

```
char BufferA[sizeof(struct A)];
char BufferB[sizeof(struct B)];
```

then write some method or mapping to return BufferA if you are working with struct A.  Speed is definitely the most important, I imagine using templates would help but I'm not sure it the whole thing can be templatized.

Update***  Sorry for not being clear, the buffers are all pre-allocated.  I just need a very fast way to get the proper Buffer given a struct type.

Update 2*** Sorry for not specifying, alignment is an important trait here and I do in fact byte-align each struct with #pragma pack(push, 1)

Comment: I'm relatively new to C++ and I believe this question has more to do with knowing some syntactic sugar more than anything...

Comment: Can you define "working with struct A". The answer may depend on how you'll be working with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "return BufferA"?  Do you mean you want your function to malloc a buffer of the appropriate size and return a pointer to it?  The way you've written this, BufferA is a stack variable and you can't return those.  Also, what do you mean by "working with struct A"?  How is that determined, and is that something that's determined at runtime or when you compile the relevant code?  Those sorts of things will determine what the answer can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename X>
struct Buffer
{
    static char *ptr()
    {
        // Note if no alignment is needed for your use then
        // just a simple "static char buf[sizeof(X)]; return buf;"
        // would be sufficient instead of the following.
        union Aligner {
            X x;
            char buf[sizeof(X)];
        };

        static Aligner a;

        return a.buf;
    }
};

struct B
{
    int x, y, z;
};

void foo()
{
    Buffer<B>::ptr()[2] = 12;
}
```

With `g++ -O2` the code above generates just a fixed memory write operation in `foo`.

```
.globl _Z3foov
    .type   _Z3foov, @function
_Z3foov:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5

    movb    $12, _ZZN6BufferI1BE3ptrEvE1a+2   <=== this is the assignment

    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Local char arrays are not guaranteed to be aligned correctly.

Comment: The OP didn't say wanted to cast a pointer to the buffer to be a pointer to an instance. It was however simple to handle that so I edited the answer.

Comment: I am in fact byte-aligning each struct, sorry for not detailing this before.  You can read my Update 2 in the OP.

Comment: I like this approach, and as it won't be byte-aligned, I think it's also pretty straight-forward and elegant.  How did you produce the assembly output and actually find the relevant location?  Very curious!

Comment: With g++ you just need to compile using `-S` option, for example `g++ -O2 -Wall -S sourcefile.cpp` will generate `sourcefile.s`. With VC++ instead you use `/FA`; for example `cl /Ox /c /FA sourcefile.cpp` will generate `sourcefile.asm`. BTW also VC++ compiles this access as a single direct write operation to a fixed memory address.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char BufferA[sizeof(struct A)];
> ```

Auto char arrays are not guaranteed to be aligned correctly.  (Alignment is guaranteed for operator new(some_size) and new char[some_size], but those are not this case.)  However, you can use compiler-specific alignment on a char array.

> I imagine using templates would help but I'm not sure it the whole thing can be templatized. … I just need a very fast way to get the proper Buffer given a struct type.

Since this is based on type, a template is the right way to go.

```
template<class T>
struct Buffer {
  static char buffer[sizeof(T)] __attribute__((aligned));  // gcc's syntax
};
```

And to access it more conveniently, rather than Buffer<A>::buffer:

```
template<class T>
inline
char* get_buffer() {
  return Buffer<T>::buffer;
}

void construct_example() {
  new (get_buffer<A>()) A();
  // same as:
  new (Buffer<A>::buffer) A();
}
```

This only allows one buffer per struct type – and that's likely to be a problem – but it seems to be what you expect and want.

Comment: Nice Fred, is new really needed?

Comment: @chriskirk: Placement new is used only to construct an object in the buffer; it does not allocate memory.  And it was only an example of how to access and use the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a template class having a numerical template parameter, and a static member for the buffer.  Something like this (not tested):

```
template <size_t S>
class GlobalBuffer
   {
   static char Buffer[S];
   };
```

Getting the buffer for a struct with a specific size can now be written like this:

```
GlobalBuffer<sizeof(struct A)>::Buffer;
```

Comment: Would this be faster than @Thomas Matthews solution below?

Comment: This has one buffer per *size* rather than per *struct.*  The difference may not matter in some cases, but it seems to matter here.

Comment: The question was to return a buffer for a given struct TYPE, not a given struct INSTANCE.

Comment: Yes, per a given struct (type) not size.

Comment: Exactly.  Given struct A { int n; }; struct B { int n; };, your solution will make GlobalBuffer<sizeof(A)>::Buffer the exact same object as GlobalBuffer<sizeof(B)>::Buffer.  This is what I meant by "this has one buffer per size".

Answer (score 0):

If the code that you're calling this from is something that literally has variables of type `A` or whatever (rather than having some sort of runtime switch), then you can use that as a template parameter when calling the function that returns the buffer.  That would look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
char *makebuffer()
{
  return malloc(sizeof(T));
}
```

Then, in your code, you write `makebuffer<A>()` and it will allocate a buffer of the correct size and return it.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:  change in the design.  Have the structures return a pointer to their prospective buffers.

According to your post, each structure *has-a* buffer associated with it.  This can be translated as *the structure has a method that will return an associated buffer*.

Something like this:

```
struct A
{
  char * get_buffer(void) const;
};
```

In the implementation file:

```
static char Buffer_A;  // Static to keep it private to this translation unit.
char * A::get_buffer(void) const
{
  return Buffer_A;
};
```

This is very efficient as far as execution goes.  It also leads to genericity.  You could put a pure virtual abstract method in a parent class for returning buffers, and thus deal with pointers or references to the parent class in your other functions.

**Note:**  The implementation above uses an automatic variable declared outside the class.  Variables declared inside a structure may be placed on the *stack* which may have smaller size restriction than a variable declared outside of the class.  Larger buffers may also be declared using dynamic memory.  See your compiler's documentation for memory capacity restrictions.

Comment: This shared buffer will lead to ugly threading/re-entrancy problems.

Comment: The variable has static storage duration (but not because of the 'static' in front it – that gives it internal linkage) rather than automatic, since it seems you place it at global scope.

Comment: @Fred: Thanks for terminology clarification.  I didn't think that `static storage duration` was a term relevant to the language.

Comment: C++03 §3.7.1 is titled "Static storage duration". :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something left of field, use a boost fusion container, specifically, [map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/map.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/at_key.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

struct A{int a, b, c;};
struct B{double a, b, c;};
struct C{bool a, b, c; };

template <class T>
struct data
{
  data() : buffer() {}

  size_t size() const { return buffer.size(); }

  boost::array<char, sizeof(T)> buffer; // assuming no alignment issues!
};

int main(void)
{
  boost::fusion::map<boost::fusion::pair<A, data<A> >,
                     boost::fusion::pair<B, data<B> >,
                     boost::fusion::pair<C, data<C> >
    > buffer_holder;

  // to access
  std::cout << boost::fusion::at_key<A>(buffer_holder).size() << std::endl; // returns reference to data<A>

  return 0;
}
```

Here, all the buffers for each type is owned by a single component, and each buffer is properly constructed and can be managed by the `data` wrapper (useful if you're in a multithreaded environment). Not a static in sight... Downside is that there is a limit to the number of template parameters you can use, you can increase this with a compiler flag (I've used up to 30 before).

Answer (score 0):

try to use unions: are resolved at compiling time and you can use with little modifications in your code.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct A_
{
    int kk;
    long long pp;
};

//
// with this kind of struct, you have instant access to A contens without memory malllocs, memory leaks,
// you can use in multithread environments, ......
// you don't need virtual tables and so on. You can inherit.......
// you don't spend more memory yhan really necesary
// you don't spend time in functions calling ...
// 

typedef struct A
{
    union
    {
        A_ a;
        char buffer[sizeof(A_)];
    };
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A a;

        // we fill the struct information
    a.a.kk = 12;
    a.a.pp = 99991829;

    A b;

        // we access to A buffer without problems
    memcpy(&b, a.buffer, sizeof(b));
    std::cout << "b.a.kk = " << b.a.kk << " b.a.pp = " << b.a.pp << std::endl;
}
```